# MongoDB Python and C++ clients - error with multiple instances

Tags: python, c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm still new to the MongoDB. My test C++ application is composed from a number of object files, and two of them have their own MongoDB instances. I've found that was a mistake, cause I've got an exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'mongocxx::v_noabi::logic_error'
  what():  cannot create a mongocxx::instance object if one has already been created
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So, I'll try to define a single MongoDB instance in this application.

And now I worry about my another application - it's top-level program in Python, which loads a number of dynamic libraries, written in C++ and having their own MongoDB instances. Where should I define the MongoDB instance - in the top-level code, in each library, in one of the libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create one shared library which manages a singleton instance of `mongocxx::instance` and have all of the other libraries which need to use the driver access that singleton via some common API. Please see the [`instance` management example](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/r3.3.0/examples/mongocxx/instance_management.cpp).

Comment: I'm looking at the example you referred to, and I think it won't work in my case, because I need to call the `configure` function more than once from multiple modules. Can you please point me to any examples, more closely related to my case?

Comment: Why do you need to call it multiple times?